# Equivalent for Help & Manual

Tags: documentation, cms

I'm trying to create a Help document for an application, but I couldn't find a program who does this.

In Windows I used to work with [Help & Manual](http://www.helpandmanual.com/products_hm_overview.html), which is a content management system for creating documentation. Isn't there an equivalent for this program in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Is it a GUI application, or command line?

Comment: it's a GUI application, for Windows we can find many programs as `Helpinator`, `HelpSmith`, `Help & Manual`...

Comment: As Ubuntu/Linux/Unix is a large and open ecosystem, there won't be a single answer.  Is this for Gtk, Qt, tcl/tk, etc.?

Comment: @belacqua I think you didn't undestand my question, I'm just looking for some software which allows me to create help manuals, you just use HTML on it.

Comment: That's fine -- I'm just try to clarify the question for others who can answer it, assuming I can't (which is likely).   I'm not at all clear on what you need yet -- what do the tools in Windows provide?  Is it html editing, html plus a template?